# Hide a div in a page and make it visible only on print bootstrap 3 MVC 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

There is a web page showing information to the user. If the user decides to print it I want to include additional information that is not required on the screen, but would be helpful when printed.

In order to implement this behaviour I was trying to make a `div` visible only for printing. It hasn't worked though:

```
<div class="visible-print hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and wondered if there is an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Define a print stylesheet. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet-2/

Comment: I think the fact you've used hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs across the div, you've effectively hidden the div across all viewports.
To simply hide or show a div for print use the following:


<div class="hidden-print">content for non print</div>

<div class="visible-print">content for print only</div>

Comment: @SkyBlues87 Your suggestion worked. If you may please put it in an answer so that I can close the question. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers Ben.  Answer added.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think the fact you've used

```
hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs
```

across the div means you've effectively hidden it across all viewports. To simply hide or show a div for print use the following:

```
<div class="hidden-print">content for non print</div>

<div class="visible-print">content for print only</div>
```

Comment: You saved my day!! Was struggling with @media print and it was not working for some controls! Thanks!!