# Check if in "mode" visible-print or hidden-print in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have code like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 visible-print">
    Stuff (print in full width)
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-print">
    Stuff (same as above but only half width for screen)
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-print">
    Other stuff (I don't want to print)
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am looking for is a function that returns true if visible-print and false if hidden-print so I can write. The code in the example is to be considered as Pseudocode

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="{{inPrintMode() ? 'col-sm-12' : 'col-sm-6'}}">
    Stuff (full width for paper, half for screen)
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-print">
    Other stuff (i don't want to print)
  </div>
</div>
```

Does this kind of function exist?
I use bootstrap and Angular

**Clarification:**
I what to style the page in one way for screen/monitor/display and another way when the page is printed on paper. I use class="visible-print" for elements that only should appear on paper, and class="hidden-print" for elements that only should appear on the screen. Elements without these tags appear on both paper and screen.

**What I am looking for how to write a function, I have called 'inPrintMode()' in this example, that detects if the user is viewing the page om a screen or if it is being rendered to be printed and returns a boolean.**

visible-print and hidden-print is talked about here:
[Hide a div in a page and make it visible only on print bootstrap 3 MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096766/hide-a-div-in-a-page-and-make-it-visible-only-on-print-bootstrap-3-mvc-5)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, but it does not answer what I am looking for. I have added a clarification to my question. I hope I have explained my problem better now. I'm looking for a way to programmatically determine if an element should be rendered. You might explain it as a way to translate 'visible-print' and 'hidden-print' to true/false. Sorry English is not my first language, plus I'm dyslexic.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there's [**`[ngClass]`**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and you can use it like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div [ngClass]="inPrintMode() ? 'class-a' : 'class-b'">
    Stuff (full width for paper, half for screen)
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-print">
    Other stuff (i don't want to print)
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqvuqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

`[ngClass]` is suitable in your case

```
<div class="row">
  <div [ngClass]="inPrintMode() == true ? 'col-sm-12' : 'col-sm-6'">
    Stuff (full width for paper, half for screen)
  </div>
  <div [ngClass]="col-sm-6 hidden-print">
    Other stuff (i don't want to print)
  </div>
</div>
```